# Why does value of a variable change inside if statement

Tags: javascript, operators

Look at this small snippet of JS:

```
var a = 1;

if(! (--a)) { // when I say --a I didn't mean to say "change the value of a" i just meant to say "without manipulating the actual value of a, just check if --a is falsy"
  console.log('ok');
}

console.log(a); // 0 ... Why? I never intended to change the value of a
```

Why is it that when I am not explicitly setting the value of a to be `--a` is the value of a being manipulated? In the `if` condition I really didn't mean to say that actually reduce the value of a, it was just an "if check" I thought would change the value of `a`.

Well I am obviously wrong I guess. I just wanted to know, is this just a JavaScript thing or is this common to all programming languages ? (I.E. being able to manipulate the value of a variable in an if condition, when actually all you want to do is temporarily manipulate the value of the variable and not change the actual value).

### Edit

I wasn't asking to explain how a-- and --a works, I want to know why does:

PROGRAMME ONE:

```
var a = 1;

--a;

console.log(a) // my expected output is 0
```

PROGRAMME TWO:

```
var a = 1;

if(--a){};

console.log(a) // my expected output is still 1 , because I didn't expect --a inside the if to actually manipulate a.
```

so basically my question is **why does `--a` work inside the if** and not HOW does `--a` work !

Comment: because it is supposed to work that way https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**if** is not only a **conditional statement** but also **executes code** written in it i.e the condition is evaluated

**eg 1:**

```
if(a == 5) {} //checking value of a
```

but

```
if(a = 5) //assigning 5 to a but also checking value of a as Undefined, null
```

**eg 2:**

Similarly in a **for...loop**

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
```

initiation, condition check and updation of value altogether gets performed

In your case
**--a** will also act as a code statement and after that it will act as a  conditional statement which will get executed and will return a value of **0** means you variable will get changed and **!** will negate it and will make it true(though it does not matter what you are asking).

```
if(! (--a)) { // when i say --a i did't mean to say "change the value of a" i just meant to say "without manupulating the actual value of a , just check if --a is falsy"
  console.log('ok');
}

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 7):

This is **Decrement (--)** operator.

> The decrement operator decrements (subtracts one from) its operand and returns a value.

***HOW does --a works***

The `--a` is equivalent to `a = a - 1`. So, when you use `--a` the value of `a` is first decremented and then used in expression. This is not specific to Javascript only, it is common to most of the programming languages.

To check if the value minus one is zero, you can use

```
if (!(a - 1)) {
```

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik This is not in Javascript only, it is common to most of the languages.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Then you'll have to clarify your question. This does exactly what you're requesting in the comments ("without manupulating the actual value of a , just check if --a is falsy")

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik, the answer above explains what you're seeing in your code. The comments in your code might explain that you didn't intend a to decrease but the code as you've written it will decrease a by 1.

Comment: @Juhana check my question noW !

Answer (score 1):

The `--` is the decrement operator. It decreases the value of the variable by one *in-place*, just as you have experienced it.

Answer (score 1):

It is the decrement operator. The decremented variable's value will be stored in the memory even if it is inside the condition expression.

You should try with the following:

```js
var a = 1;
var b = a - 1;
if (!(b)) {
  console.log('ok');
}

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

**someNumber--** will read the variable value first and then subract 1 from it.

**--someNumber** will first detract 1 and then read the variable value.

Regardless, it *will* modify the value.

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question then. Are you confused as to why the variable is changed, or possibly the scope of the variable?

Answer (score 0):

the `--` and `++` operators are 'execution'-type operators, and they are being evaluated within call.

you should use this syntax:

```
if(!(a - 1)) { 
  console.log('ok');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`--a` is an *expression* that, having first decremented `a`, has a value of the *new* value of `a`.

This is true for C, C++, Java, and Javascript.

If you want to check if `a - 1` *would* be false, then write `if (!(a - 1))` or, more clearly `if (a == 1)`. Either of those expressions does not change the value of `a`.